# Not able to playback AES-128 encrypted HLS video stream on iOS 13 beta 3 simulator

Tags: avfoundation, aes, avplayer, http-live-streaming, ios13

Since iOS 13 beta AES-128 encrypted HLS video stream playback stopped working for me ***on iOS Simulator*** (I use either AVPlayer/AVPlayerLayer or AVPlayer/AVPlayerViewController approach). For example:

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let url = URL(string:"https://video-dev.github.io/streams/dai-discontinuity-deltatre/manifest.m3u8")!
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    playerViewController.player = player
    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        playerViewController.player?.play()
    }
}
```

I've also tried to playback not encrypted HLS streams and they seem to work fine on iOS 13 beta iOS Simulator. For example [this one](https://video-dev.github.io/streams/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8) works as expected. Playback of the same video streams works fine on iOS 12 (both iOS device and simulator).

So question is: do you also have the same issue? If so, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: It’s beta software. Nothing is guaranteed to work. Open a ticket in radar, and wait for the next release.

Comment: I've already opened a radar, but was thinking that maybe somebody has the same issue and was able to find temporary fix.

Comment: Issue was fixed in iOS 13 beta 5.